# what's wrong with this d3 onmouseover attempt?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've created a simple webpage with a simple svg and I'm trying to wireup a basic onmouseover event to trigger a simple alert.  I've tried a few different approaches but I'm not able to get it to work:

https://jsbin.com/cefanis/edit?html

Any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to find an DOM node before it's been (I'm not sure of the proper terminology here) initialized? rendered?. Move the `script` element to after the referenced node (`#simpleCircle` in this case)

```
<svg id="simpleCircle">
    <circle id="myCircle" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="blue"></circle>
<svg>

<script>    
    d3.select('#simpleCircle')
      .select('#myCircle')
      .on('mouseover', hiThere);

    function hiThere(d) {
        alert('hi there');
    }   
</script>
```